# Can not access tty terminal

Tags: boot, lightdm, gdm, tty, display-manager

My `HP Probook` has problems with `Display manager`. Basically, for now I can not access even login page (While I am on login page, I can access `tty` isn't it ? But it is unreachable for now).

I do not know how to solve this problem. I want to get `tty` without login page, and then just upload several projects on `github` using `command-line`. How I can achieve it ?

I see message `A start job is running for hold untill boot process finishes up`, and it never finishes working.

Comment: Please start by provided your OS & release details, it gives us a clue as to your software stack, and why you've included `lightdm` & `gdm` tags as they are not used both default for any on-topic OS here  (*you may have followed some instructions intended for one type system that caused you to install the other DM, but we don't know your starting point, nor what instructions you followed, nor if they were intended for your software stack; ie. your OS & release details we don't currently know*)

Comment: Hello, I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I am getting message, Lightdm display manager stopped working

Comment: Please add additional details to your question (you can edit your own question), also I assume you mean Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop, however it doesn't come with `lightdm` so it it cannot work as it's not installed.  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Desktop uses the GNOME desktop which uses GNOME's `gdm3` (a cut-down version of GNOME shell as greeter; it's more efficient since it uses GNOME calls to perform many functions & GNOME is installed because you're using GNOME desktop).